# Why does spotlight incorrectly calculate modular powers?

Tags: macos, spotlight

Spotlight does not calculate the correct result of `(31^x) % 35` where `x >= 11`?. It shows for `x=12`
[image]
while the correct result is `1`. How can this be? It works for all smaller powers of `31` modulo `35`.

Comment: You are using very large numbers. It seems like you're hitting some kind of upper bound or an overflow.

If you try to do [the same calculation with Google's builtin calculator](https://www.google.de/search?q=(31%5E10)%2535%3D) it will also fail for exponents bigger than 10.

Comment: That was my guess, but if you simply try to exponentiate with large numbers, it will say `No Results` instead of calculating garbage.

Comment: "Why" do people write code that contain bugs, seems like an unanswerable question.  Since the project manager for Spotlight isn't going to come in and respond to this question, it seems unlikely you will get an answer as to the reasoning, if any, behind why this bug exists.

Comment: @DonSimon If that's what it is, yes. There might have been some obscure explanation for it. I guess I'll file a report for this.